# Java ParNew Collection moving objects to Old Generation

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection

That's my VM arguments:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m 
-XX:+UseParNewGC 
-XX:MaxNewSize=1G 
-XX:NewSize=1G 
-Xms13G 
-Xmx13G 
-XX:SurvivorRatio=128 
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0 
-XX:+UseTLAB 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-verbose:gc 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps 
-Xloggc:./gc.log -cp
```

I have also created memory leak:

```
{
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < objectsCount; i++)
        s += "s" + s;
}//Here all created objects should be garbage collected
```

So i have run that part of the code few times and i noticed that most of the objects are moved to Old Generation and only some are collected by small GC

```
832.135: [GC 832.135: [ParNew: 1032095K->0K(1040512K), 0.7309045 secs] 4832264K->4761739K(13623424K), 0.7309703 secs] [Times: user=2.37 sys=0.33, real=0.73 secs] 
833.148: [GC 833.148: [ParNew: 826257K->0K(1040512K), 0.1510836 secs] 5587996K->5095138K(13623424K), 0.1511436 secs] [Times: user=0.33 sys=0.00, real=0.15 secs] 
833.567: [GC 833.567: [ParNew: 742459K->0K(1040512K), 0.2067575 secs] 5837597K->5836296K(13623424K), 0.2068291 secs] [Times: user=0.75 sys=0.00, real=0.21 secs] 
853.490: [GC 853.582: [ParNew: 993475K->0K(1040512K), 0.6963577 secs] 8100247K->7107608K(13623424K), 0.6968597 secs] [Times: user=1.61 sys=0.00, real=0.79 secs] 
879.973: [GC 879.973: [ParNew: 1032433K->0K(1040512K), 10.6403908 secs] 8140042K->8061725K(13623424K), 10.6404844 secs] [Times: user=30.93 sys=0.34, real=10.64 secs]
```

I think reason is, too many objects are pasted to memory in the same time so its more convenient for garbage collector to move them from Young Generation or Old Generation.

My question is, what should i change in my arguments, to make all of those objects be cleared by Small GC?

Answer (score 0):

move the String s = "" inside the loop and then try.

The thing here is that until the for loop completes the variable s is not marked for GC. The GC log entries you see are while the for loop is going on. Because the program runs out of young gen space and for loop is still running the GC collector moves the values of S to old gen because it doesnt know what else to do.

---

instead of doing this

```
String s = "";
for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
    s = s + "something";
}
```

Do it like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
    String s = "something";
    //call some methods to process it.
}
```

or use a StringBuilder to create the string concatenation instead of using the + operator on Strings.

---

```
-d64 -server -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:NewSize=1536m -XX:MaxNewSize=1536m -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:ParallelGCThreads=14 -XX:ConcGCThreads=14
```

adjust the perm size as you see fit. NewSize is your young gen and rest what is left of the heap allocation goes to old gen. try with this and see if it helps you.

Comment: "Because the program runs out of young gen space and for loop is still running the GC collector moves the values of S to old gen because it doesnt know what else to do." - Yeah, is there anything i can do about that? Because then all objects like that in my program will be marked as long-time-variables and they need to wait for Collection which will take a look into Old Generation.

Comment: thats what i said in my answer. Create the variables inside the loop not outside. check the edit in my answer

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < objectsCount; i++)
{
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
 b.append("asd");//If now garbage is collected, object b would be moved to Old Generation.
 b.append("dsa");
} And i dont want it to be moved

Comment: what makes you believe it would be moved to old generation? b is only active for a single iteration of the for loop. So when iteration finishes b finishes. It becomes eligible for GC unless u leak a reference to b before the iteration finishes. By the way whats the fascination with young generation? If it does go into old generation in your existing code then whats the trouble? The odl gen would be GCed during a major GC cycle and that would recover the memory.

Comment: "Because the program runs out of young gen space and for loop is still running the GC collector moves the values of S to old gen because it doesnt know what else to do." - Here you told me, that if b object is currently used(b.append("asd")) then GC moves b to old gen. Major GC stops VM for too long time

Comment: yeah major GC stops VM because you have a 13 gb of heap allocated. this would give a bout 9-10 GB of memory to old gen and scavanging that would take time. Try to reduce your heap size to about 6 to 8 gb and you should have smaller GC pauses. have you though about using the CMS colector instead of Parallel collector?

Comment: I am currently using UseConcMarkSweepGC, i also checked without UseParNewGC argument but result is the same. Having 6-8 gb of memory to check is still too big amount.

Comment: let me give you something i think will help you with a good run. see the edit in answer

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain your JVM arguments for you.

`-XX:NewSize=1G` - this is size of young space (one collected with "small" collection).

`-XX:SurvivorRatio=128` - this will split young space as ~1008 MiB of Enden + 2 survivor spaces 8 MiB each. Young ("small") collection happens when Eden is filled up.

`-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0` - this parameter forced JVM to immediately promote objects survived one young GC to old space (so survivor spaces are never used). Normally object should survive several "small" GC before being promoted to old space, but you have explicitly disabled it.

[Here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html) you can find more details about generational collection in HotSpot JVM.

[Cheatsheet of HotSpot GC options](http://blog.ragozin.info/2013/11/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html) may also be useful.